# Vaadin accordion expand by default last Tab

Tags: vaadin7

I want a  Vaadin accordin to expand by default last Tabs  as show in image B. (tabs are dinamically created)

[image]

Comment: Soo, what did you try so far and what issue did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

It could be do it in this way:

```
main(){
    dinamically_load_accordion();
    accordion.setSelectedTab( last_added);
}

dinamically_load_accordion(){
    while( ) {
         last_added = accordion.addTab(this.tree, tittle);
    }
}
```